# looping a switch statement in C# has strange error

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, fall-through

I'm recently learning C# but I've run into a problem.

```
public static void PlayGame(Kion Player1,Kion Player2)
    {
        bool Win = false;
        Console.WriteLine ("Let us begin then");
        Console.WriteLine ("Press Enter to roll the dice ");
        Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Random Dice = new Random();
        while (Win == false)
        {
            int DiceResult = Dice.Next (1,6);

            switch(DiceResult)   ***control cannot fall-through from one case label to another error message here***
            {
            case 1:
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine ("The attribute being played is Strength");
                if ((Player1.Pride == "Kan") & (Player2.Pride == "Kan"))
                    Console.WriteLine ("You are both proud Kans, you match in combat and do not lose health");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine ("Those who belong to the 'Kan' pride unleashes their claws");
                    if (Player1.Pride == "Kan")
                {
                    Player2.LoseHealth();
                    int PlayerNumber = 2;
                    LoseHealthText(PlayerNumber, Player2);
                }
                    else
                    if (Player2.Pride == "Kan")
                {
                    Player1.LoseHealth ();
                    int PlayerNumber = 1;
                    LoseHealthText(PlayerNumber, Player1);
                }
                    else 
                    Console.WriteLine ("None belong to the Kan, you will all hide this turn");
                break;

            case 3:
            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine ("hello");
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above cannot execute because the compiler reports an error of `control cannot fall-through from case label to another` on the line where there is the `switch(DiceResult)` statement.

Can someone help my identify where my mistake is?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Please actually ask a question.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?  or at least a representative subset of it so we see the whole loop and what you do at the end of case 4, etc. ?

Comment: Please post the rest of the `switch` statement - it's difficult to diagnose the problem with half the code.

Comment: Are you aware, that you will never throw a 6, because the second argument of `Random.Next(int min, int max)` is "one greater than the greatest legal return value"? Use "`Dice.Next (1,7)`" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 3:
case 6:
    Console.WriteLine ("hello");
```

Here you need a `break;` statement, like this:

```
case 3:
case 6:
    Console.WriteLine ("hello");
    break;
```

In `C#`, you can't create a `case` option without `break;`, `return;` or `throw` statement. [Please refer MSDN|](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a break after

```
Console.WriteLine ("The attribute being played is Strength");
```

so you have:

```
 switch(DiceResult) // **control cannot fall through case on this line**
            {
            case 1:
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine ("The attribute being played is Strength");
            break;
            }
```